# Add or replace object to array with dynamic key name in javascript (reactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a number of select, when i onChange them i want to keep in componente state the selected value
the onChange function i call do something like this:

```
function validateVariations(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.name);

    setSelected((selected) => [
      ...selected,
      { [event.target.name]: event.target.value },
    ]);

    .... //OTHER PROCESS
 }
```

basically i add to state select an object like:

```
[{Weight: "250"},{Pack: "Tin"}]
```

but using it a couple of time it fill up with the history changes like this:

```
[{Weight: "250"},{Weight: "500"},{Weight: "250"},{Pack: "Tin"}, {Pack: "Card"}]
```

so i need to add the `{ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }` only if its not present an object with key `[event.target.name]`, otherwise i need to replace it.

i tried using findIndex but im not able to reference to a dynamically named key

this is not working:

```
var i = data.findIndex(function(e) {
    return e.[event.target.name] == event.target.name;
});
```

any elegant solution?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the format of your data, you could use this:

```
var i = data.findIndex(function(e) {
    return Object.keys(e)[0] === event.target.name;
});
```